# It's true that policy file in drush prevents sql-sync from local to prod?

Tags: drush

I know in the policies file in drush there was/is a way to prevent sql-sync'ing from local to prod.

Is this still true? If so how do you go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this is still true you can find the relevant snippet in the drush source code:

```
/**
 * Implement of drush_hook_COMMAND_validate().
 *
 * Prevent catastrophic braino. Note that this file has to be local to the machine
 * that intitiates sql-sync command.
 */
function drush_policy_sql_sync_validate($source = NULL, $destination = NULL) {
  if ($destination == '@prod') {
    return drush_set_error(dt('Per examples/policy.drush.inc, you may never overwrite the production database.'));
  }
}
```

You should include the policy.drush.inc in your .drush folder usually located in the users home folder.

Comment: Can you add this to the server to enforce the policy?

Comment: No, as per the comment this has to go on the machine that executes the command.

Comment: Can this be added to a module in the drupal site?

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you must decide is where would you like to keep the policy file, and this really depends on your purpose for creating the policy file in the first place. If you are just wanting to prevent yourself from doing something crazy by accident, or if there is special functionality for you, you can add the policy to the .drush directory inside your home directory.

If you are wanting to have a different policy for different sites or Drupal installs, you might think about adding the policy file to the /sites/all/drush directory; this also makes it handy for versioning the file. To have a global policy file that will work for all sites and users on a server, your best bet is to put the policy file in the /usr/share/drush/command directory.

Each of these directories is valid though they aren’t inclusive, meaning that if you have a file in your /sites/all/drush directory, the settings here will overwrite the settings you may have in your ~/.drush directory. Likewise, the policy file in the /usr/share/drush/command directory will overwrite any other policy file, which is what we want, so someone can’t circumvent restrictions by creating their own policy.drush.inc file and adding it to their home directory.

Example of policy.drush.inc file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implementation of drush_hook_COMMAND_validate().
 */
function drush_policy_sql_sync_validate($source = NULL, $destination = NULL) {
  if ($destination == '@prod') {
    return drush_set_error(dt('Permission denied! You almost overwrote the production database you moron!'));
  }
}
```

See also:

- examples at [policy.drush.inc API page](http://api.drush.ws/api/drush/examples%21policy.drush.inc),
- [Limiting Drush access with a policy configuration](https://www.appliedtrust.com/blog/2012/05/limiting-drush-access-with-a-policy-configuration)